# OOP PHP with PDO Connection including different page class

Tags: php, class, oop, pdo, extends

class/dbConnect.php page

```
class dbConnect {
    /*
     * initiate mysql database host,username,password,database name
     */

    private $host;
    private $dbName;
    private $uname;
    private $upass;
    private $con;

    public function __construct($host, $database, $userName, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbName = $database;
        $this->uname = $userName;
        $this->upass = $password;
        $this->connectDB();
    }

    public function connectDB() {
        /*
         * @var $dsn mean data source name for pdo connection
         */
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbName=" . $this->dbName;
        try {
            $this->con = new PDO($dsn, $this->uname, $this->upass);            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

class/sampleView.php

/*
 * include dbConnect class for this SampleView Class Page
 */
require_once './dbConnect.php';



class sampleViews extends dbConnect{

     function viewUsers(){
         /*
          * dbConncect Class Connection variable access
          */
         $connection = $this->con;

     }
}
```

is this way Correct??? I can't Access dbConnect Class $con varibale Using $this-> method withing the sampleView Class

and can be able to done Different Location Class extend including page in this way..Help Plezzzz

Comment: change properties from `private` to `protected`

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `private` variables even when extending the parent class. You need to change it to `protected`:

```
protected $con;
```

You'll also need to construct the parent class, otherwise it won't ever instantiate the parent(extended) class.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct($host, $username, $password, $db);
}
```

<sup>*The above would be inside your `class SimpleViews extends dbConnect {....` class*</sup>

Comment: you, beat me by 2 secs.

Comment: @RichardChristensen Haha took me a while to format that code :P

Comment: One recommendation here though would be to inject a `DbConnect` object into your view class to eliminate the need to `parent::__construct();`

Comment: @RichardChristensen I would've gone the exact same way!! I'll throw that up, was just answering to the OP's question scope!

Comment: No problems, OOP design is my fetish.

Comment: You and I both, you and I both @RichardChristensen

Answer (score 0):

dbConnect page

changed

```
protected $host;
protected $dbName;
protected $uname;
protected $upass;
protected $con;
```

and SampleView page

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct('localhostr', 'test', 'root', '');
}

function chkConnection() {
    /*
     * dbConncect Class Connection variable access
     */
    $dbcon = $this->con;
    if ($dbcon) {
        echo "successfully Connect database";
    } else {
        echo "sorry Could not be connect databsae";
    }
}
```

Would somebody correct my code?

Comment: On top of what @Fred said, you don't want your `host/username/password/db` to be accessible outside of the class. So they should stay `private`.